# sh: 1: tailwindcss: Permission denied / tailwindcss

Tags: command-line, permissions, programming

I have a problem while run the **build command** from Tailwindcss (i am using tailwindcss CLI):

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/css/output.css --watch
```

While running this command, it puts an output like the following:

```
sh: 1: tailwindcss: Permission denied
```

I have already reinstalled nodejs and npm. The versions are: nodejs:`v18.2.0`, npm:`8.11.0`

The folder permissions are the following:

```
jonas@jonas-ubuntu ~/D/G/WOWA-BAU-NEU (main)> ls -la
insgesamt 100
drwxrwxr-x  8 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 ./
drwxrwxr-x  3 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 25 22:53 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas 11701 Mai 23 21:47 build.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas     0 Mai 23 21:47 file
drwxrwxr-x  8 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 31 14:59 .git/
drwxrwxr-x 59 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 node_modules/
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 old/
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas    60 Mai 23 21:47 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas 45723 Mai 23 21:47 package-lock.json
drwxrwxr-x  5 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 30 13:51 public/
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 src/
-rw-rw-r--  1 jonas jonas   108 Mai 23 21:47 tailwind.config.js
drwxrwxr-x  2 jonas jonas  4096 Mai 23 21:47 .vscode/
```

for me they look correct to read, write and execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem after a new installation of Ubuntu what worked for me was this solution:

```
npm rebuild
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831494/sh-1-cross-env-permission-denied-on-laravel-mix

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete ***node_modules*** then run **`npm i`** . Worked for me